# Problem with run sprint-boot activiti app - 'process' cannot have character [childresn]

Tags: spring-boot, maven, activiti

- The pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <activiti.version>5.22.0</activiti.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

- the app:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @RestController
    public static class MyRestComtroller{
        @Autowired
        private RuntimeService runtimeService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/start-my-process",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public void startMyProcess(){
            runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("test");
            System.out.println("we have now" + runtimeService.createNativeProcessInstanceQuery().count() + "process instances");

        }
    }



}
```

- the error :
   `org.activiti.bpmn.exceptions.XMLException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'process' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.`

except of this error I'm also get a few warning -
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

- the procces : in the procces have  error on the definition - Element definitions must be declared. (this bpmn20.xml file create by alfresco)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn"
             xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
             xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"
             typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath"
             targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef" xmlns:modeler="http://activiti.com/modeler"
             modeler:version="1.0en" modeler:exportDateTime="20220303040839752" modeler:modelId="1"
             modeler:modelVersion="1" modeler:modelLastUpdated="1646273308964"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://activiti.com/modeler ">
  <process id="test" name="test" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startEvent1">
      <extensionElements>
        <modeler:editor-resource-id><![CDATA[startEvent1]]></modeler:editor-resource-id>
      </extensionElements>
    </startEvent>
    <userTask id="sid-C4EB4721-09B1-455C-9E6A-FB310EAA193E" name="a" activiti:assignee="$INITIATOR">
      <extensionElements>
        <modeler:allow-send-email><![CDATA[true]]></modeler:allow-send-email>
        <modeler:activiti-idm-initiator><![CDATA[true]]></modeler:activiti-idm-initiator>
        <modeler:editor-resource-id><![CDATA[sid-C4EB4721-09B1-455C-9E6A-FB310EAA193E]]></modeler:editor-resource-id>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    test.bpmn20.xml
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-ACECCB48-5BFE-4C0F-A323-CB46E9A69256" sourceRef="startEvent1"
                  targetRef="sid-C4EB4721-09B1-455C-9E6A-FB310EAA193E">
      <extensionElements>
        <modeler:editor-resource-id><![CDATA[sid-ACECCB48-5BFE-4C0F-A323-CB46E9A69256]]></modeler:editor-resource-id>
      </extensionElements>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="sid-9F06F0E6-7474-4E56-88E9-F0E284A50A44" name="b" activiti:assignee="$INITIATOR">
      <extensionElements>
        <modeler:allow-send-email><![CDATA[true]]></modeler:allow-send-email>
        <modeler:activiti-idm-initiator><![CDATA[true]]></modeler:activiti-idm-initiator>
        <modeler:editor-resource-id><![CDATA[sid-9F06F0E6-7474-4E56-88E9-F0E284A50A44]]></modeler:editor-resource-id>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-22578A3C-8439-4E94-9A10-1CD6B52789BB" sourceRef="sid-C4EB4721-09B1-455C-9E6A-FB310EAA193E"
                  targetRef="sid-9F06F0E6-7474-4E56-88E9-F0E284A50A44">
      <extensionElements>
        <modeler:editor-resource-id><![CDATA[sid-22578A3C-8439-4E94-9A10-1CD6B52789BB]]></modeler:editor-resource-id>
      </extensionElements>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="sid-5A3C22BE-C0B3-4016-A595-529C94B7C84D">
      <extensionElements>
        <modeler:editor-resource-id><![CDATA[sid-5A3C22BE-C0B3-4016-A595-529C94B7C84D]]></modeler:editor-resource-id>
      </extensionElements>
    </endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-CAF1B715-1BF8-4B48-A5A6-62CC0E4870FE" sourceRef="sid-9F06F0E6-7474-4E56-88E9-F0E284A50A44"
                  targetRef="sid-5A3C22BE-C0B3-4016-A595-529C94B7C84D">
      <extensionElements>
        <modeler:editor-resource-id><![CDATA[sid-CAF1B715-1BF8-4B48-A5A6-62CC0E4870FE]]></modeler:editor-resource-id>
      </extensionElements>
    </sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_test">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="test" id="BPMNPlane_test">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startEvent1" id="BPMNShape_startEvent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="60.0" y="75.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-C4EB4721-09B1-455C-9E6A-FB310EAA193E"
                        id="BPMNShape_sid-C4EB4721-09B1-455C-9E6A-FB310EAA193E">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="135.0" y="50.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-9F06F0E6-7474-4E56-88E9-F0E284A50A44"
                        id="BPMNShape_sid-9F06F0E6-7474-4E56-88E9-F0E284A50A44">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="280.0" y="50.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-5A3C22BE-C0B3-4016-A595-529C94B7C84D"
                        id="BPMNShape_sid-5A3C22BE-C0B3-4016-A595-529C94B7C84D">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="28.0" width="28.0" x="425.0" y="76.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-ACECCB48-5BFE-4C0F-A323-CB46E9A69256"
                       id="BPMNEdge_sid-ACECCB48-5BFE-4C0F-A323-CB46E9A69256">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="90.0" y="90.0"/>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="135.0" y="90.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-22578A3C-8439-4E94-9A10-1CD6B52789BB"
                       id="BPMNEdge_sid-22578A3C-8439-4E94-9A10-1CD6B52789BB">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="235.0" y="90.0"/>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="280.0" y="90.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-CAF1B715-1BF8-4B48-A5A6-62CC0E4870FE"
                       id="BPMNEdge_sid-CAF1B715-1BF8-4B48-A5A6-62CC0E4870FE">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="380.0" y="90.0"/>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="425.0" y="90.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

- the procces : in the procces have  error on the definition - Element definitions must be declared. (this bpmn20.xml file create by alfresco)

Comment: "test.bpmn20.xml" this line I am showing in *.bpmn, is this by mistake?

Comment: yes/////////\\\

Comment: Same code I have tried removing "test.bpmn20.xml" from bpmn file and it is working.

Comment: But if I'm wanna combine in the spring-boot app bpmn file that is a process, how can I do this?

Comment: Did not get what you want to achive?

Comment: now the app run but if I'm run in terminal the process - curl localhost:8282/start-my-process the app throe the error - [nio-8282-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: You sprint-boot app started properly?